# interactive multiple file upload in different variables using R

Tags: r, file-upload, interactive

I am trying to let user define how many drugs' data user want to upload for specific therapy. Based on that number my function want to let user select data for that many drugs and store them using variables e.g. drug_1_data, drug_2_data, etc.
I have wrote a code but it doesn't work
Could someone please help

```
no_drugs <- readline("how many drugs for this therapy? Ans:")
i=0

while(i < no_drugs) {
  i <- i+1
  caption_to_add <- paste("drug",i, sep = "_")
  mydata <- choose.files( caption = caption_to_add) # caption describes data for which drug
  file_name <- noquote(paste("drug", i, "data", sep = "_")) # to create variable that will save uploaded .csv file
  file_name  <- read.csv(mydata[i],header=TRUE, sep = "\t")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `mydata` is a one element string, so subsets with `i` bigger than 1 will return `NA`. Furthermore, in your first assignment of `file_name`  you set it to a non-quoted character vector but then overwrite it with data (and in every iteration of the loop you lose the data you created in the previous step). I think what you wanted was something more in the line of:

```
file_name <- paste("drug", i, "data", sep = "_")
assign(file_name, read.delim(mydata, header=TRUE)
# I changed the function to read.delim since the separator is a tab
```

However, I would also recommend to think about putting all the data in a list (it might be easier to apply operations to multiple drug dataframes like that), using something like this:

```
n_drugs <- as.numeric(readline("how many drugs for this therapy? Ans:"))
drugs <- vector("list", n_drugs)

for(i in 1:n_drugs) {
    caption_to_add <- paste("drug",i, sep = "_")
    mydata <- choose.files( caption = caption_to_add)
    drugs[i]  <- read.delim(mydata,header=TRUE) 

}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.